# Automatically redirect from '/folder' to '/folder/index.html' with Hakyll or another issue with relative links

Tags: html, haskell, redirect, relative-path, hakyll

I want to implement static HTML website with multiple languages using Hakyll framework. I didn't come up with better solution than just put default language under `website.com` route and any other custom language at `website.com/en` route. Because I'm using static HTML and having multiple languages I should have multiple versions of every page, for example `about.html`. Such pages are generated automatically, so that's not a problem. But currently I have a problem with jumping those pages...

I have such link in my `website.com/index.html`:

```
<a href=about.html>
```

When I open this link from `website.com/en` I want to jump to `website.com/en/about.html` instead of `website.com/about.html`. But in reality I'm jumping from `website.com/en` to `website.com/about.html`. If I instead jump from `website.com/en/index.html` I go to `website.com/en/about.html` as I want. So I'm inserested in one of two possible solutions:

1. When I go to `website.com/en` I want to be redirected to `website.com/en/index.html`. I can see content of `index.html` from `website.com/en` but somehow I can't jump to relative link :(
2. Replace `href=about.html` with something more smart so I can automatically go `folder/about.html` from any folder.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `website.com/en` redirect to `website.com/en/index.html`, from where that relative link does indeed work?

Comment: @Bergi This is exactly what I've asked for: `When I go to website.com/en I want to be redirected to website.com/en/index.html`. When I need to go to `website.com/en` from any link on my I can manually set this link to `website.com/en/index.html` but it's still possible in Hakyll (as I can see) to enter manually `website.com/en` directly in browser address bar and the resulting link will look like `website.com/en/`. I don't know to automatically redirect this to `index.html`.

Comment: Are you using an Apache webserver? With [`DirectorySlash On`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) and [`DirectoryIndex index.html`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) (both of which are the defaults), the `website.com/en` should be 301-redirected to `website.com/en/` which in turn will display the content of the index.html file, and relative links on that url do work for me.

Comment: @Bergi Hmm, I'm not aware of DevOps part of web-server deployment. But as I see now `website.com/en` redirects to `website.com/en/` indeed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: html redirects are not good practice, why won't you use .htaccess or the backend redirect (say PHP)?